# Trying to understand the Gaussian Transform in the $k^{th}$ reduction of a Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, gaussian-elimination

The main role of the gaussian transform is to force the entries of a matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ to be such that the $k^{th}$ entry of $A$ during the $k^{th}$ Gaussian reduction has all entries below it $0$. Thereby repeating this operation creates an upper triangular matrix. Therefore, define the matrix: $$M^{(k)}:=I-u^{(k)}e_{k}^{T}$$
where for $x=A(:,k)$, we define $u^{(k)}:=\begin{bmatrix}0&\cdots&\frac{x_{k+1}}{x_{k}}&\cdots&\frac{x_{n}}{x_{k}}\end{bmatrix}$

---

For the first reduction, we have:
$$
u^{(1)}=\begin{bmatrix}0&\frac{x_{2}}{x_{1}}&\cdots&\frac{x_{n}}{x_{1}}\end{bmatrix}
$$
Therefore :
$$
M^{(1)}=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0&\cdots &0\\
-\frac{a_{2,1}}{a_{1,1}}&1&\cdots&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
-\frac{a_{n,1}}{a_{1,1}}&0&\cdots&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

---

I am having a hard time understanding the matrix-matrix multiplication between $M^{(1)}$ and $A$ to obtain $A^{(1)}$ and I would hope someone can help me understand it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first reduction, what we have is the vector $^{(1)}$ such that :
$$
\mathbf{u^{(1)}}=\begin{bmatrix}0&\displaystyle\frac{x_{2}}{x_{1}}&\cdots&\displaystyle\frac{x_{n}}{x_{1}}\end{bmatrix}
$$
Therefore :
$$
\mathbf{M^{(1)}}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
-a_{2,1} / a_{1,1} & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
\vdots & 0 & \ddots & \ddots & 0 & 0 \\
-a_{j, 1} / a_{1,1} & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \vdots \\
\vdots & 0 & 0 & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\
-a_{n, 1} / a_{1,1} & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The main key to perform the product of the two matrices $M^{(1)}$ and $A$ is to divide the two matrices into blocks because you will see that for the first, second, ..., last reduction, there will be some operations repeated at every reduction
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{M^{(1)}A}&=\left[\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
\hline-a_{2,1} / a_{1,1} & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
\vdots & 0 & \ddots & \ddots & 0 & 0 \\
-a_{j, 1} / a_{1,1} & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \vdots \\
\vdots & 0 & 0 & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\
-a_{n, 1} / a_{1,1} & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & \cdots & a_{1, j} & \cdots & a_{1, n} \\[0.05cm]
\hline a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & \cdots & a_{2, j} & \cdots & a_{2, n} \\[0.05cm]
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\[0.05cm]
a_{i, 1} & a_{i, 2} & \cdots & a_{i, j} & \cdots & a_{i, n} \\[0.05cm]
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\[0.05cm]
a_{n, 1} & a_{n, 2} & \cdots & a_{n, j} & \cdots & a_{n, n}
\end{array}\right]\\\\
&=
\left[\begin{array}{c|c}
\mathbf{A^{(1)}}(1,:)\\
& \mathbf{A^{(1)}}(2:n,2:n)\\
\mathbf{A^{(1)}}(2:n,1)
\end{array}\right] \\ \\
&=\mathbf{A^{(1)}}
\end{align*}
By subdividing the matrices into block, one can see that to obtain the first row of $A^{(1)}$, then all you have to do is multiply the first row of $M^{(1)}$ with $A$ which happens to be the first row of $A$ preserved i.e.,
\begin{align}
A^{(1)}(1,:)&=M^{(1)}(1,:)*A\\
&=e_{1}^{\intercal}A\\
&=A(1,:)
\end{align}
Moreover, the first column of $A^{(1)}$ should be $0$ for all entries below the pivot $A^{(1)}(1,1)$ which is what this operation is meant to achieve in the first reduction. This can be seen since multiplying $M^{(1)}$ with first column of $A$ should result in cancellation of the entries. For instance :
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-a_{2,1}/a_{1,1}&1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1,1}\\
a_{2,1}
\end{bmatrix}
=-a_{2,1}+a_{2,1}=0
$$
Therefore we may express the second block as :
\begin{align}
A^{(1)}(2:n,1)&=M(2:n,:)*A(:,1)\\
&=\operatorname{zeros}(n-1,1)
\end{align}
Similar observation allow us to express the third block as follow :
\begin{align}
M^{(1)}(2: n,:) * A(:, 2: n)&=M^{(1)}(2: n, 1) * A(1,2: n)+M^{(1)}(2: n, 2: n) * A(2: n, 2: n) \\
&=A(2: n, 2: n)+M^{(1)}(2: n, 1) * A(1,2: n)
\end{align}

---

**[Example]**

Consider the following matrix :
$$
\mathbf{A}:=\left[\begin{array}{llll}1 & -1 & 2 & 1 \\ 3 & 2 & 1 & 4 \\ 5 & 8 & 6 & 3 \\ 4 & 2 & 5 & 3\end{array}\right]
$$
We have that :$$
\mathbf{u^{(1)}}=\begin{bmatrix}0&\frac{A(2:4,1)}{A(1,1)}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0&3&5&4\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
\mathbf{A^{(1)}}=\mathbf{M^{(1)} A}=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
-3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
-5 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
-4 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 2 & 1 \\
3 & 2 & 1 & 4 \\
5 & 8 & 6 & 3 \\
4 & 2 & 5 & 3
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & 5 & -5 & 1 \\
0 & 13 & -4 & -2 \\
0 & 6 & -3 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
as mentioned earlier, the first row is preserved, the first column below $A^{(1)}(1,1)$ have their entries wiped out and the rest of the entries are computed through vector-vector multiplication between rows of $M^{(1)}$ and columns of $A$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation

Comment: You are very much welcome $:$-$)$